# Disable Nginx-Modsecurity in a different location while using Nginx as a reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I have a problem, where I have a backend server that is Behind an Nginx Reverse Proxy which is running libmodsecurity.

I want to enable libmodsecurity for the entire site but one Page.

It isn't very easy to explain so I'll show my code.

```
server {
  listen 80;           
  listen 443 ssl;      
             
       if ($scheme != "https"){                        
               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

       }

       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_cert/wildcard_example_com.pem;           
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_cert/wildcard_example_com.pem;    
   

  server_name a.example.com;   


  location / {     
      proxy_pass https://IpAdress:Port;     #address of the Backend-Server
       proxy_set_header Host $host;                                    
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                        
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    


# Modsecurity is turned on automatically but it can be disabled by #modsecurity off;


  }

# now I want to disable ModSecurity for example.com/index.html#!/users

  location = /index.html#!/users {
      proxy_pass  https://IpAdress:Port/index.html#!/users;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;                                    
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                        
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
      


        modsecurity off;

  }

}
```

**Disclaimer** I am not using Nginx as a webserver so i don't even know if it works with different locations

When I try this configuration nginx does not throw any errors but it doesn't Work. ModSecurity still protects the URL example.com/index.html#!/users

Comment: I'm not sure the substring after `#` character is still part of location. That's an anchor and it's for the client.